# Meteor.js accounts-facebook allows US facebook account but not German OAuth error

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am working on a Meteor App that uses the accounts-facebook package. The package works perfect for my Facebook account which was opened in the US. I created another Facebook account in Germany and am trying to log into the application with the German account from a different browser with no cookies already existing.

I click the Sign in with Facebook button and get the page to log into facebook. After that I get a Internal Server error popup with a Dismiss button. The app does not log in.

The error I get in the console is as follows:

```
I202309-13:49:31.607(2)? Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Facebook. failed [400] {"error":{"message":"Invalid verification code format.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
I202309-13:49:31.607(2)?     at getTokenResponse (packages/facebook/facebook_server.js:62)
I202309-13:49:31.608(2)?     at Object.isJSON [as handleOauthRequest] (packages/facebook/facebook_server.js:8)
I202309-13:49:31.608(2)?     at Oauth._requestHandlers.(anonymous function) (packages/oauth2/oauth2_server.js:9)
I202309-13:49:31.608(2)?     at middleware (packages/oauth/oauth_server.js:105)
I202309-13:49:31.608(2)?     at service (packages/oauth/oauth_server.js:78)
```

I double checked my Facebook token and secret which match perfectly what they are supposed to be. Like I said before, I can log in with my other facebook account I created in the US but not with the one created in Germany.

Is there maybe a difference in Facebook's OAuth system for European accounts or is this some weird bug in the package? Does anyone have a clue on how to go about fixing this issue because I would like users from all nations to log in with facebook?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue and it turns out "sandbox mode" was enabled for my Facebook app! Make sure sandbox mode is disabled in your Facebook app configuration and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem. You have to configure your app on facebook to be available for general public.

[your app] -> Status & Review 
- Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? (yes)